# How change the url of an image within an html page in a django project?

Tags: python, html, django, angular

I'm new to Django. I have 2 images, one for NP environment and one for Production environment. I have to make each image stay in its given environment. This is to be done in an html page within Django.
This html page is the body of an email.

can you help me?

The image looks like below. And I want to control her link according to the environment she is in

```
<td bgcolor="#fff" align="right" style="padding: 21px 19px 18px">
                            <img alt="Teste"
                                src="https://.../mail/logo.png"
                                width="210px" />
</td>
```

Comment: I presume you are already using templates in Django.  You just have to make the src be a variable in the template, and pass that from your Python.